# Some of the events that are created using calendar API are not opening in mobile browser-CHROME

Tags: google-chrome, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

visit the link from mobile browser-CHROME (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar-demo)
then navigate to September 7th and click on the event.

After clicking on the event nothing is happening, can someone help me with this?

[mobile-browser-chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqxj1.png)

thanks in advance.

Comment: It worked when I tried it. First it asked me if I wanted to open the link either in Chrome or in the Calendar app, I chose Chrome and then it took me to the correct URL and showed the event - I was redirected to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month/2020/9/7?eid=MjAyMDA5MDdfNjBvMzBkcjVjNG8zMGUxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmcgZW4udXNhI2hvbGlkYXlAdg&pli=1&sf=true . I don't see a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There seem to be some issues with certain phones. It's not working on my mobile and others. Try with other mobile devices.

Comment: If you want anyone to be able to help with this you'll need to give some examples of specific devices where it doesn't work - state the device, the Android version and the Chrome version in each case.